# How to graphically simulate the result of the K-Means Algorithm?

Tags: java, algorithm, simulation, k-means

I'm a student in computing sciences in Paris. In mathematics this year we have to use the K-means algorithm to solve a problem (the Clustered Capacited Vehicle Routing Problem applied to the resupplying of self-service bicycles' stations). Here is my algorithm :

```
public void run() {
    boolean hasConverged = false;
    List<Integer> nearestClusters = null;

    //A list used to check if the nearestClusters list has evolved
    //If it isn't the case, the algorithm is finish
    List<Integer> previousList = new ArrayList<Integer>();

    //Random initialization of the clusters' centroids
    for (int i = 0; i < clustersNumber; ++i) {
        clusters.add(ClusterGenerator.Generate(stationsList,colorList.get(i) ,latMin, latMax, lngMin, lngMax));
    }

    while (!hasConverged) {

        if (nearestClusters != null) {
            previousList.clear();
            previousList.addAll(nearestClusters);
        }

        nearestClusters= new ArrayList<Integer>();

        //Each point is connected to it nearest cluster
        for (int j = 0; j < stationsList.size(); ++j) {
            nearestClusters.add(getIndexOfTheNearestCluster(stationsList.get(j)));
        }

        //We move the clusters centroids to the center of the points they are connected to
        for (int k = 0; k < clusters.size(); ++k) {
            clusters.get(k).setCentre(stationsCenters(getStationsOfCluster(clusters.get(k), nearestClusters)));
        }

        if (!nearestClusters.isEmpty() && previousList.equals(nearestClusters))
            hasConverged = true;
    }
}
```

Yet, I wanted to show the result of my algorithm with the clusters formed and I found this work on the Internet : https://github.com/ertugrulozcan/K-Means-Simulation

I imported in my project the class ClusterGenerator which creates clusters along with random elements, the class Item, the class Graphic (I didn't touch anything there) and the class MainWindow which initiates all the graphic elements.

I did not manage to display the plots and there are no errors in Eclipse that could give me any clue.

Can someone please explain to me where is the problem ?

Thanks

Comment: Since it is an eclipse project I would recommend you to just get the source folders and create the project yourself. The project as it is is with his configurations files. And use java 1.8 that is what he is using.

Comment: Also: your question-title and your question within the question are two very different things!

Comment: The program cited is incorrectly synchronized; any result is possible; see [*Initial Threads*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/initial.html). Also, "Swing programs should override `paintComponent()` instead of overriding `paint()`."—[*Painting in AWT and Swing: The Paint Methods*](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/painting-140037.html#callbacks).

Comment: Hi, sorry for the way I asked my question. I edited it. Thanks for your answers. It's the first time I uses graphic interfaces in Java. So I don't know what does mean my program is not correctly synchronized. How could I make it synchronized ?

Comment: @MichelRahal Looks better, thanks for the update. The other things I'd recommend improving are: 1) Your third paragraph is quite dense and reads like a wall of text, 2) maybe remove the commented out code (is it important, or just outdated?), 3) fix your code indentation in the second and third code blocks, and 4) I can generally figure out what you were getting at with the French words in the code, but you might want to translate everything to English anyway. Unfortunately I don't have experience with the UI setup you are using, but I hope you find the answer you're looking for.

Comment: I found the solution ! Thanks to you all for your interest.

Answer (score 1):

The problem was that my algorithm was generating clusters for the stations but I did not configure the class Graphic (which I understood later was very important for the display) to render correctly my points. Since, I used latitude and longitude as coordinates for my station, I had to put these coordinates to scale for the window. Here is how I did that (using cross multiplications) : I calculate the "gap" between two units in the graph and added an adjustment because I don't start at zero.

```
double gapX = (this.getWidth() - 2 * edgeSpace) / (topX-bottomX+1); 
int adjustmentX =(int) (-bottomX*gapX);
```

(getWidth() gives the actual width of the panel where is the graph, edgespace is the padding space between the graph and the edge of the panel, topX is the maximum value of a coordinate and bottomX the minimum value)